# What is the best approach to save ecommerce data on blockchain?

Tags: mongodb, e-commerce, blockchain, bigchaindb

I'm setting up a blockchain database using `bigchaindb` for an ecommerce platform. Although, it's more like a secure backup. My application already runs on a SQL database. The blockchain database saves data in the form of assets and transactions in `mongodb`. The `bigchaindb` also provides all it's data via a public API. Later, I also want to query this database.

I tried searching for it, but didn't get a dedicated discussion on database design for e-commerce on blockchain. If you know any such article out there, let me know, it'll be helpful.

As per my personal assertions:
Every information like, the user_profile, order, products, reviews etc can be saved in the form of assets. Moreover, operations like transferring product from the seller to the customer can be saved as transactions. Also, a customer creates a review as an asset, while putting the review on the product will be a transaction.

Of course, I will need to create Key-Pairs as identities for individual users, but I think I shouldn't save it in the blockchain, as it's data is accessible by the public API. So, I can save it in the actual SQL database of the application.

Do you think it's the best way? Any suggestions from your side?

Comment: So why blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can have a "schema" in a / any blockchain. For your purpose, which I believe is little strange https://github.com/ssbc/ssb-db should be enough.